# AVPlayer doesn't switch from Audio-Only to Video stream

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, http-live-streaming, avplayeritem

I'm using AVPlayer to play the HTTP Live stream. Often I observed that AVPlayer switches to Audio-Only mode when the network is Low, but when the network recovers to High, it doesn't switch to Video stream or takes very long to switch to Video stream.

I did a test to observe the behaviour closely by simulating the Low network conditions using "Network Link Conditioner" in my iPad and my observations are same i.e AVPlayer doesn't switch to Video stream or takes a very long time.

Is anyone else facing this problem? or Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Vasu

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I observe the same from time to time.